# Toastr Notification Display Text on Top Of Each Other Instead of New Line

Tags: javascript, css, toastr

I am using Toastr to display simple messages to the user. I include the toastr.css and toastr.js files in my application. I override a few default options as shown below. When the message is displayed to the user, it display in 1 lines when it's supposed to be 2 lines. The second part of the message appear under the first line, so the user can't read the message. If I change the positionClass option to full-with, it will display the message. However, I am trying not to use the full length.

```
    var option = {
        closeButton : true,
        closeMethod : 'fadeOut',
        closeEasing : 'swing'
    }

 toastr.Error('You must select a students', 'Student Page', option);
```

Comment: can put your example in a jsfiddle?, this will make it much easier to see the issue

Comment: I tried this and it auto carriage return, line feeds.